# Как сделать чтобы другая строка пропадала при выводи другой в Python?

Tags: python

Я хочу сделать так чтобы Python убирал выше выведенную строку или заменял на другую строку. Например выводиться "Hello" он убирается и заменяется на "World!". Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого Вам надо сделать две вещи:

1. У первой строки убрать перенос каретки
2. У второй строки добавить возврат каретки.

**Важно учитывать**, что первая строка не удаляется, а на нее сверху ложиться вторая, поэтому если вторая меньше первой, то первая затрется не до конца.

```
from time import sleep

# end='' уберет перенос каретки (по-умолчанию end='\n')
print('Hello', end='')

# добавил паузу, иначе Вы увидите только вторую строку
sleep(2)

# \r добавит возврат каретки
print('\rWorld!')
```

Comment: Я бы `flush=True` ещё добавил на всякий.